# How to Add a field that asks for more details under product display just like add to cart/add to wishlist?

Tags: views, commerce

I have an e-commerce site , i want to add a link or a button under each product display to ask about price with view integration, if i click on it i will be redirected to a form to add my informations.Any help will be appreciated.